# PHP Snippet Issue

Tags: php, linux, apache2, php-7

I have a PHP file (myFile.php) that parses XML, and assigns the data I need to a variable ($myVar). I need to echo this variable on an HTML page. I’ve tried adding `<?php include ‘/myFile.php’; echo $myVar; ?>` to the HTML file to no avail, however if I call the script itself (http://localhost/myFile.php) and add `echo $myVar;` to the end of the file the data is displayed as expected.

Am I missing something simple? I’m running PHP7 on a Linux Apache server - is there a setting somewhere that I need to change? I’ve used this syntax in the past without issue.

Thank you for the second set of eyes!

Comment: Why do you have a leading `/` in your `include` statement? You have to specify the path on disk, not the URI of the file. In your case, `/` would mean that the file is in the root directory of your server and not within the `DocumentRoot` which is configured in the Apache settings.

Comment: Does "HTML page" mean a static file with ".html" extension that the server is not configured to parse as PHP? Are you really using typographic quotes (`‘`) instead of regular quotes (`'`)? What role does NetBeans play in the script execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myFile.php';
    echo $myVar;
?>
```